# Convert the following code from Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am new to Python and I am trying to convert and modify the following [code](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/158357-create-random-points-in-a-rectangular-domain-but-with-minimum-separation-distance) from Matlab to python:

This is what I have so far ( I am also trying to make it for 3 dimensions):

```py
import random
import numpy as np

L = 21.1632573
x = np.random.uniform(low=0.0000,high=L,size=10000) 
y = np.random.uniform(low=0.0000,high=L,size=10000) 
z = np.random.uniform(low=0.0000,high=L,size=10000) 


prox = 1
N = 20

#First Point
firstX = x[0]
firstY = y[0]
firstZ = z[0]

counter = 0
for k in range(1,N):
    thisX = x[k]
    thisY = y[k]
    thisZ = z[k]
    distances = np.sqrt((thisX-firstX)**2+(thisY-firstY)**2+(thisZ-firstZ)**2)
    minDistance = np.min(distances)
    if minDistance >= prox:
        firstX[counter] = thisX
        firstY[counter] = thisY
        firstZ[counter] = thisZ
        counter = counter + 1
```

However, I am having a problem in the last if statement:

```
File "/home/aperego/codes/LJ_Problem1/canonical/randomParticles.py", 
line 26, in <module> firstX[counter] = thisX

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstX, firstY and firstZ are numbers so you can't use firstX[index]. So define them as list or array (if you know the final length).

I read your matlab code, I corrected it and plotted accordingly.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

L = 21.1632573
x = np.random.uniform(low=0.0000,high=L,size=10000) 
y = np.random.uniform(low=0.0000,high=L,size=10000) 
z = np.random.uniform(low=0.0000,high=L,size=10000) 

prox = 1
N = 20

#First Point
firstX = [x[0]]
firstY = [y[0]]
firstZ = [z[0]]

counter = 0
for k in range(1,N):
    distances = np.sqrt((x[k]-firstX)**2+(y[k]-firstY)**2+(z[k]-firstZ)**2)
    minDistance = np.min(distances)
    if minDistance >= prox:
        firstX.append(x[k])
        firstY.append(y[k])
        firstZ.append(z[k])
        counter = counter + 1

##Plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(firstX,firstY,firstZ, c='b', marker='*')
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you assign numpy float to those variables. those variables should be list

```
firstX = x[0]  # all numpy.float64
firstY = y[0]
firstZ = z[0]
```

you should append new point to list

```
import random
import numpy as np

L = 21.1632573
x = np.random.uniform(low=0.0000,high=L,size=10000) 
y = np.random.uniform(low=0.0000,high=L,size=10000) 
z = np.random.uniform(low=0.0000,high=L,size=10000) 


prox = 1
N = 20

#First Point
firstX = [x[0]]
firstY = [y[0]]
firstZ = [z[0]]

for k in range(1,N):
    thisX = x[k]
    thisY = y[k]
    thisZ = z[k]
    distances = np.sqrt((thisX-firstX[0])**2+(thisY-firstY[0])**2+(thisZ-firstZ[0])**2)
    minDistance = np.min(distances)
    if minDistance >= prox:
        firstX.append(thisX)
        firstY.append(thisY)
        first.append(thisZ)
```